# Planned Exploratory Test Charters - Categorisation in JIRA

Tags: testing, jira

I've created a number of these over time documenting the testing of various major features, and at the moment they are all under a single 'Task' in JIRA which is a bit messy, but very easy to find as they're always in one place.

However, should these really be linked to each Story they test, or under a separate 'Requirements Trace' linked to that story?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried Zephyr for Jira?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I create ET charters in Jira I add them as individual stories and then link them as a related "Linked Issue" to whatever subtask or story that was covered by the exploration. This way there is some description of what testing is done.

Within the ET charter story, I'll write summaries of my sessions (if using Session Based Test Management) and then once I've satisfied my curiosity or feel satisfactory about that charter, I'll mark it as resolved.

ET charters are super helpful for dealing with larger features or changes, but I will do more free form / charter-less testing with smaller features. That's one reason I don't link them as requirements because they are optional.